# Chocolaty install of Google Chrome fails HASH check

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, chocolatey

I am getting an error when installing Google Chrome Browser in powershell using chocolatey. It works when I by-parse the hash check, but how do I make sure this is fixed in nuget?

I can install other packages.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> choco install googlechrome
Chocolatey v0.10.11
Installing the following packages:
googlechrome
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading GoogleChrome 71.0.3578.80... 100%

GoogleChrome v71.0.3578.80 [Approved]
googlechrome package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package GoogleChrome wants to run 'chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[N]o/[P]rint): y

Using system proxy server 'server.proxy.com:8081'.
File appears to be downloaded already. Verifying with package checksum to determine if it needs to be redownloaded.
Error - hashes do not match. Actual value was 'E080C523B419D0F706B3633FCBCE37ADA61F983BDEAB1084E3320C69BA2134A4'.
Downloading googlechrome 64 bit
  from 'https://dl.google.com/tag/s/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi'
Using system proxy server 'proxy.jp.sbibits.com:8080'.
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\GoogleChrome\71.0.3578.80\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi (53.85 MB).
Download of googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi (53.85 MB) completed.
Error - hashes do not match. Actual value was 'E080C523B419D0F706B3633FCBCE37ADA61F983BDEAB1084E3320C69BA2134A4'.
ERROR: Checksum for 'C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\GoogleChrome\71.0.3578.80\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi' did not meet 'a4e5e5562b1ef9bd6a3b28ff66f37ddefba2d5b60e6f49f8a9981703bef0587e' for checksum type 'sha256'. Consider passing the actual checksums through with --checksum --checksum64 once you validate the checksums are appropriate. A less secure option is to pass --ignore-checksums if necessary.
The install of googlechrome was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\GoogleChrome\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

Comment: Please edit the question - I don't see a question mark in the original question or indication of what research has been done.  One might try clearing the local file and downloading again.  One might try other chocolatey installs and see if they succeed.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Made it a bit more clear now.

Comment: try with the install latest flag.  Outside of that, wait for google to fix their broken choco pkg.  They forgot to change the hash in the install script when they repackaged.  Either that, or someone intercepted your shit and sent you hacked code.

Comment: @Colyn1337 The point is now I don't know which one it is, so prefer if they fix it as source.

Comment: This is happening again and it's hard to conclude that Google would *forget* to set the correct hash code - 2 yrs later.... I think this is dodgy and the way Choco protects us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Google have a single URL for downloading the Google Chrome installer, and they update the version behind that URL.

Sadly, this means that Chocolatey Packages that refer to that URL (without using the CDN, or having internalized the binaries) will have a hash-mismatch.

Strictly, this is a good thing, as if you were expecting to install Chrome v2.0 (for example) but installed v16.0 (or someone was trying to make you install a malicious MSI), you did not get what you requested.

The general solution is to either:

- Install the latest version of Chrome from the CCR, which should have a matching hash
- Internalize the package by including the binary at the time of creation (and then host it in a repository yourself) *or*
- Bypass the hash checks